# Content editable div - Insert new 'p class' after caret / selected div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

I have a project in which a content editable div is parent then using jQuery I wish to add p tags inside this div. Which can then also be edited. Almost like a mini note pad document.

The problem I have is that i'm using the jQuery .append function on the parent div which adds the p class to the end of the div. What I need it to do is add the p class after the current selected p / the p the caret cursor is currently inside.

jQuery I am currently using -

```
  $(".addHeading").click(function() {
     $('.textArea').append('<div class="heading">Heading</div>');
  });

  $(".addParagraph").click(function() {
     $('.textArea').append('<div class="paragraph">Test</div>');
  });​
```

I have put my current code into a JSFiddle. I hope it's obvious what i'm trying to do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

JS Fiddle - 
http://jsfiddle.net/eheHS/

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding a click handler to your newly created paragraph divs, you can save away the last one that was edited. Here's one solution, but not very elegant ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aKtSt/)):

```
var $lastCaretDiv;

$(".addParagraph").click(function() {
    if ($lastCaretDiv) {
        $lastCaretDiv.after($('<div/>', {
            'html': 'Test',
            'class': 'paragraph'           
        }).click(function () {
            $lastCaretDiv = $(this);
        }));
    } else {
        $('.textArea').append($('<div/>', {
            'html': 'Test',
            'class': 'paragraph'           
        }).click(function () {
            $lastCaretDiv = $(this);
        }));
    }
});
```

This will set `$lastCaretDiv` to the last one that was clicked. If it is defined, then add the new paragraph after it, otherwise append it to the text area.

My solution has a lot of pitfalls as it is right now, but you have something to work after. I would suggest clearing `$lastCaretDiv` whenever something else in the text area is clicked, e.g. a header. It all depends on how you want it to behave.

Comment: You could use jQuery's `focusin` and `focusout`, but for some reason they don't work when the parent `div#textAreaID` is `contentEditable`. Even when using `event.stopPropagation()`, the `div#textAreaID` always gets the `focus` event and not the `div.paragraph`.

Comment: For some reason, the `div`s won't get focus unless the [`tabindex`](http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Creating_Logical_Tab_Order_with_the_Tabindex_Attribute) property is set. This however disables the keyboard navigation with anything other than tab.

Answer (score 0):

On first inspection McFjodor's answer is what I'm after.

Seems to work fine. I've tweaked and duplicated his code to also do the same for the headings text.

Amended javascript as below:

```
var $lastCaretDiv;

$(".addHeading").click(function() {
if ($lastCaretDiv) {
    //$lastCaretDiv.after('<div class="paragraph">Test</div>');
    $lastCaretDiv.after($('<div/>', {
        'html': 'Heading',
        'class': 'heading'            
    }).click(function () {
        $lastCaretDiv = $(this);
    }));
} else {
    $('.textArea').append($('<div/>', {
        'html': 'Heading',
        'class': 'heading'            
    }).click(function () {
        $lastCaretDiv = $(this);
    }));
}
});



$(".addParagraph").click(function() {
if ($lastCaretDiv) {
    //$lastCaretDiv.after('<div class="paragraph">Test</div>');
    $lastCaretDiv.after($('<div/>', {
        'html': 'Test',
        'class': 'paragraph'            
    }).click(function () {
        $lastCaretDiv = $(this);
    }));
} else {
    $('.textArea').append($('<div/>', {
        'html': 'Test',
        'class': 'paragraph'            
    }).click(function () {
        $lastCaretDiv = $(this);
    }));
}
});​
```

Below is a completed fiddle of what I was after based on McFjodors answer!

http://jsfiddle.net/aKtSt/2/

This Works for now if I come across any problems with this method I will update.

Thanks!